# Bones change size in Pose vs Rest State, can't clear

Tags: animation, unity

Am trying to bake animations for moving mixed actions from NLA Strips to Unity, and I am running into this odd problem with scaling. I've been using LocRot this entire time, but somehow when I try to bake a pose, scaling goes to hell and the model looks awful. An issue that may be related is the rest position (Small bones below) and the pose position (Big bones below) are different, despite me clearing all rotations, scaling, etc.

Normal, desired rest position-
[image]

Pose mode, no matter what I try clearing - 
[image]

Edit:  For some reason the individual bone, still had scaling up to 2.0 even when cleared in pose mode. I don't know why Alt-S wouldn't take care of this. Despite fixing this, when I bake a pose, or key frame one with scale (I've used LocRot the entire time) I get the following:

[image]

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please use the question editor to add images on this site so they are permanent and also directly embedded into your post.

Comment: Sorry, fixed it.

Comment: What kind of modifiers your bones have, could they cause the difference?